# How to use UserDefault on an Array in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a checklist app that has several arrays with checks. I'd like to save the state if a users closes/quits the app. I was thinking of using the UserDefault methods for this:

```
HStack {
          ForEach(0 ..< checklist.steps) { index in
               VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                          self.checked[index].toggle()
                          UserDefaults.standard.set(self.checked[index], forKey: "Check")
```

I'm currently using the following state for checks:

```
 @State private var checked = [false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Does anyone know how to apply UserDefaults for arrays or generally how to save the state for your app when closing it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: (it is the code from last time ;)) i think the true/false settings itself is not correct, but the saving / loading works ;)

```
struct ChecklistView: View {
    var checklist: Checklist
    @State var currentProgress: Float = 0.0
    @State var checked : [Bool] = [false, false, false, false]

    init(checklist: Checklist) {
        self.checklist = checklist

    }

    func saveUserDefaults() {

        var value = ""

        for eachValue in checked {
            if eachValue == true { value += "1" }
            else { value += "0" }
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: checklist.title)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

            //            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            //                .foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.5)
            //                .frame(width: 200)

            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    checklist.image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(checklist.title)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)

                        Text(checklist.instruction.uppercased()).font(.system(size: 12))

                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0 ..< checklist.steps) { index in
                                VStack {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.checked[index].toggle()
                                        print(self.checked)
                                        self.saveUserDefaults()

                                    }) {
                                        ZStack {

                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                                .foregroundColor(self.checked[index] ? Color("LightGreen") : .gray )
                                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)

                                            Image(systemName: self.checked[index] ?  "checkmark" : "plus")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                                                .foregroundColor(self.checked[index] ? .white : .white)

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(width: 350, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            if let values = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: self.checklist.title) as? String {

                self.checked = values.map {
                    if $0 == "1" { return true }
                    return false
                }
            }
            print(self.checked)
        }
        .frame(width: 350)
        .padding(.bottom, 16)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .padding(.top, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello again Chris!! Thank you so much for helping again ;). Your method works, however, if I click on 1 checkbox at category fruit for example. That exact same checkbox changes to "true" in all other categories when I relaunch the app. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Maybe the checklist.title is the same on them?

Comment: It was because of the checklist.title indeed!! It works perfectly, thanks ya'll!

Comment: Is there also a way to reset everything to false on the next day?

Comment: just write your current day in userdefaults, when you are saving. compare this with the current date when you are loading. if it is another day -> reset

Comment: I will try that :)! Thanks a lot

Comment: `.onAppear() {
                
                if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self.today) == false {
                    UserDefaults.resetStandardUserDefaults()
                    
                }
                print("check datum")
                
                if let values = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: self.checklist.title) as? String {         self.checked = values.map {
                        if $0 == "1" { return true }
                        return false
                    }
                }
                print(self.checked)
            }`

Comment: Place where I save the date: 
`func saveUserDefaults() {
        _ = Date()
        var value = ""
        
        for eachValue in checked {
            if eachValue == true { value += "1" }
            else { value += "0" }
            
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: checklist.title)
    }
`

Comment: And I've added a `let today = Date()`, to compare the values with. It isn't working yet.. haha But I think I'm getting closer (A)

Comment: resetStandardUserDefaults()
This method has no effect and shouldn't be used. -> Apple Documentation

Comment: you have to delete your userdefaults yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test that solution, but can't you store your array in your NSUserdefaults after every button action?

```
Button(action: {
    self.checked[index].toggle()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.checked, forKey: "Check")
```

Probably, the best solution would be using `CoreData` for that, which would be very easier to use.

PS: I can test that solution later on.. not at my Mac right now

Comment: Interesting. I'm fairly new to Swift(UI). Will also check CoreData! Do you have any tips regarding use of CoreData in this case?

Comment: @JoëlvanBodegraven I am using CoreData in my new project and it really is great. You just create a model, which would be one item of your checklist. This stores the name and the status. If you change the stauts (done/ or not done) you save that to CoreData and everything is done